# x64 assembly literal with vs without $

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, 64-bit

I am just starting out learning x86_64 assembly I'm using gcc on linux to assemble my code.

What I am finding confusing is the difference between a literal with a $ vs one without.

The following code works:

```
.global main

.text

main:
    movq $0xffffffffffffffff, %rax

    xor %rax, %rax
    ret
```

but if I remote the $ from the constant then it segfaults, so the code that dies is:

```
.global main

.text

main:
    movq 0xffffffffffffffff, %rax

    xor %rax, %rax
    ret
```

could someone please explain this to me and if the second is not valid why does gcc assemble it and not complain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a C-like pseudo-language, your first example is something like:

```
rax = 0xffffffffffffffff;
```

Your second is:

```
rax = *(uint64_t *)0xffffffffffffffff;
```

The second example almost certainly segfaults, as you're seeing.  It's still a valid instruction, though, so there's no reason for your tools not to assemble it.